# Android Annotation with Kotlin

Tags: android, annotations, kotlin

I can't run Android Annotation with Kotlin Android Project.
When i try run my application with link to MainActivity_, my app is crashed. But i mark Activity class with @EActivity

> Unable to instantiate activity
>   ComponentInfo{ru.lionzxy.jetbrainsintership/ru.lionzxy.jetbrainsintership.MainActivity_}

I try add

```
kapt {
    generateStubs = true
    arguments {
        arg("androidManifestFile", variant.outputs[0].processResourcesTask.manifestFile)
    }
}
```

and

```
kapt "org.androidannotations:androidannotations:$AAVersion"
compile "org.androidannotations:androidannotations-api:$AAVersion"
```

in my build.gradle file. Clean and build. And get this error:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'.
>
> > Compilation error. See log for more details

My log file in /app/build/outputs/logs/manifest-merger-debug-report.txt:
https://gist.github.com/LionZXY/bf398a3b64f787a56d985a5a0ea03bfe

I don't understand why it not work. 
My full build.gradle: https://gist.github.com/LionZXY/4e672579fe89ad22cea07d2fe15a1621

Comment: That's not the right log. Can you post the output of `gradlew.bat assembleDebug`/`./gradlew assembleDebug`?

Comment: $ ./gradlew clean assembleDebug >> output.log
https://gist.github.com/LionZXY/4a737b35f95fc40ff33a6c975ae08a9f

Comment: Weird, only warnings in that log, not errors, yet it fails kapt. Can you try making `mSearchView` and `mRecyclerView` `protected` instead of `private`?

Answer (score 0):

Annotations are means of attaching metadata to code. Annotations are supported in Kotlin with kapt plugin.Please ensure kotlin latest version 1.3 + 
You can apply plugin syntax in module-level build file as follows

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
```

Then you can add dependency

```
dependencies {
...
implementation 'androidx.room:room-runtime:2.1.0-alpha04'
kapt 'androidx.room:room-compiler:2.1.0-alpha04'
}
```